# xpath how to format path

Tags: python, xpath

I would like to get @src value '/pol_il_DECK-SANTA-CRUZ-STAR-WARS-EMPIRE-STRIKES-BACK-POSTER-8-25-20135.jpg' from webpage

```
from lxml import html
import requests
URL = 'http://systemsklep.pl/pol_m_Kategorie_Deskorolka_Deski-281.html'
session = requests.session()
page = session.get(URL)
HTMLn = html.fromstring(page.content)
print    HTMLn.xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[19]/div/a[2]/div/div/img/@src')[0]
```

but I can't. No matter how I format xpath, i tdooesnt work.

Comment: Which image are you trying to get? There isn't an obvious problem in your XPath. It just doesn't address any specific image. Indexing into a document like this (e.g. `div[3]/div[19]/div/a[2]`) is extremely specific and very fragile. Better to cite some local landmarks--the ids or classes of elements close to the one you want to extract.

Comment: Additionally, the site you're trying to grab an img location from appears to be using JavaScript and AJAX calls to dynamically fill page content as the user scrolls. That has the potential to make simple HTTP request-based scraping much more challenging (possibly impossible). Often, scraping those sites requires using a remote-control browser against them (e.g. Selenium, PhantomJS, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of [@pmuntima's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42741625/240490), if you already know it's the 14th sourced image, but want to stay with `lxml`, then you can:

```py
print HTMLn.xpath('//img/@data-src')[14]
```

To get that particular image. It similarly reports:

```
/pol_il_DECK-SANTA-CRUZ-STAR-WARS-EMPIRE-STRIKES-BACK-POSTER-8-25-20135.jpg
```

If you want to do your indexing in XPath (possibly more efficient in very large result sets), then:

```py
print HTMLn.xpath('(//img/@data-src)[14]')[0]
```

It's a little bit uglier, given the need to parenthesize in the XPath, and then to index out the first element of the list that `.xpath` always returns.

Still, as discussed in the comments above, strictly numerical indexing is generally a fragile scraping pattern.

---

Update: So why is the XPath given by browser inspect tools not leading to the right element? Because the content seen by a browser, after a dynamic JavaScript-based update process, is different from the content seen by your request. Your request is not running JS, and is doing no such updates. Different content, different address needed--if the address is static and fragile, at any rate.

Part of the updates here seem to be taking `src` URIs, which initially point to an "I'm loading!" gif, and replacing them with the "real" `src` values, which are found in the `data-src` attribute to begin.

So you need two changes:

1. a stronger way to address the content you want (a way that doesn't break when you move from browser inspect to program fetch) and
2. to fetch the URIs you want from `data-src` not `src`, because in your program fetch, the JS has not done its load-and-switch trick the way it did in the browser.

If you know text associated with the target image, that can be the trick. E.g.:

```py
search_phrase = 'DECK SANTA CRUZ STAR WARS EMPIRE STRIKES BACK POSTER'
path = '//img[contains(@alt, "{}")]/@data-src'.format(search_phrase)
print HTMLn.xpath(path)[0]
```

This works because the `alt` attribute contains the target text. You look for images that have the search phrase contained in their `alt` attributes, then fetch the corresponding `data-src` values.

Comment: How did you know that it is the 14th sourced image and how did know the name "data-src"? If I look a this elemnt using chrome i can see <img class="b-lazy b-loaded" src="/pol_il_DECK-SANTA-CRUZ-STAR-WARS-EMPIRE-STRIKES-BACK-POSTER-8-25-20135.jpg" alt="DECK SANTA CRUZ STAR WARS EMPIRE STRIKES BACK POSTER 8,25"> and th xpath for this is //*[@id="search"]/div[19]/div/a[2]/div/div/img

Comment: Therein lies the rub. Sure, that's the XPath to the content you want **as your browser sees the content, after the dynamic loads**. When you use a programmatic request, the content may not be filled in the same way. And in this case, does not appear to be. That hyper-specific XPath doesn't work on even slightly differently-structured content--like the content that `requests` hands back to you.

Comment: The 14 was chosen by hand, because that's what works in this instance. To make this a repeatable process, you need a way of specifying or addressing the content that doesn't require fragile instructions like "turn right at the 19th red light"--because "19 red lights" is going to be a time- and context-dependent address. Not a robust, repeatable one.

Comment: @MichałRzepecki Updated the answer to illustrate content-based search. It is a bit more robust than depending on broswer-specific XPath, which is notoriously fickle.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of `requests` and `beautiful soup` libraries. They both are wonderful and I would recommend them for scraping and parsing/extracting HTML. If you have a complex scraping job, `scrapy` is really good.

So for your specific example, I can do

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'http://systemsklep.pl/pol_m_Kategorie_Deskorolka_Deski-281.html'
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
specific_element = soup.find_all('a', class_="product-icon")[14]
res = specific_element.find('img')["data-src"]
print(res)
```

It will print out

`/pol_il_DECK-SANTA-CRUZ-STAR-WARS-EMPIRE-STRIKES-BACK-POSTER-8-25-20135.jpg`

Comment: How did you know that it is the 14th sourced image and how did know the name "data-src"? If I look a this elemnt using chrome i can see <img class="b-lazy b-loaded" src="/pol_il_DECK-SANTA-CRUZ-STAR-WARS-EMPIRE-STRIKES-BACK-POSTER-8-25-20135.jpg" alt="DECK SANTA CRUZ STAR WARS EMPIRE STRIKES BACK POSTER 8,25"> and th xpath for this is //*[@id="search"]/div[19]/div/a[2]/div/div/img